# Error while running elasticsearch using puppet

Tags: elasticsearch, centos, puppet

My puppet config is:

```
class { 'elasticsearch':
      java_install => true,
      manage_repo  => true,
      repo_version => '2.x',
      version => "2.4.4",
  }

elasticsearch::instance { 'es-01': }
```

After running puppet agent got this error:

```
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Section "base" is already defined, cannot redefine in /etc/yum.repos.d/centos.repo
```

Elasticsearch is running on centos-7

Comment: What module are you using?

Comment: puppet-elasticsearch module from forge

Comment: Sounds like a bug, but I notice you already posted an issue on the tracker.

Comment: Yup posted on github tracker.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by puppet pre-fetching the yum repos.

If there are more than one repository with the same label you will see your `already defined` error when puppet is set to use `Yumrepo`.   The error will show the first duplicate alphabetically and abort.

You can reproduce the error following these steps: `duplicate a .repo`, `apply manifest with yumrepo`

Initial Repo:

```
puppet apply -e "yumrepo { 'test': ensure => 'present', baseurl => 'http://test/repourl', descr => 'test' }"
```

Then duplicate the repo so you have two [test] repos:

```
cp -p /etc/yum.repos.d/test.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/test2.repo
```

Now any attempt to use puppet with `Yumrepo` fails, reproduced below:

```
# puppet apply -e "yumrepo { 'someapp': ensure => 'present', baseurl => 'http://test/repourl', descr => 'some app' }"
```

...which yields the following error:

`Error: Failed to apply catalog: Section "test" is already defined, cannot redefine in /etc/yum.repos.d/test2.repo`

For your error, see which files are duplicating `[base]`:

```
grep '^\[base]$' /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo
```